# How to control audio player in the lock screen?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

Sometimes there are buttons for music control in the lock screen (next/previous song, play/pause), but sometimes they're not shown in the lock screen and I have to unlock my iPod Touch and click the buttons. I'm wondering when will the buttons show on the lock screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to double click the home button to get the controls to display.

Comment: Is there any apps to make it display whenever home button is clicked?

Comment: This is also true in apps. If you're in Safari, for instance, if you double click the home button, it will show you the controls. Just remember that you have to activate this behavior yourself from Settings.